# Automator: start embedded YouTube

Tags: applescript, video, automator, google-chrome, youtube

So, I need to show some kids a sequence of YouTube videos (with Automator, because there's no one available to man the computer for 30 minutes), but it's at a school where the YouTube domain is blocked, so I had to use a workaround where I use a website (http://www.safeshare.tv) that will embed a YouTube link for me into a page, and I can view the embedded video from there.

However, it does not automatically start the embedded video. So, I have my Automator configured to open a video in Chrome, then wait for the predetermined  length of the video (AppleScript `delay` command), then open another video, then wait some more, etc.

However, when it opens each video, they don't start playing. Watch Me Do crashes for anything I try to do, even the simplest mouse movements, so that is out.

How do I make it play the embedded video? Is there anything I can do with AppleScript? Is there a Chrome plugin that automatically plays embedded YouTube videos on a page when the page is opened? Is there a similar Automator plugin?

Maybe I could just ask SafeShare to edit their service for one day so that their YouTube embeds start automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **[YouTube Options for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options-for-googl/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn?hl=en-GB)** extension.

There's an option to auto play embedded videos. (according to screenshots of the Chrome webstore).

If this doesn't fit your needs, if think there are other options. Just give me your feed back please.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. EDIT: Hmm, now the problem is, that as every new video pops up, all embedded video across every tab starts playing, all over again. How do I close a Chrome tab with Automator?

Comment: Nvm, that was a problem with me not segregating inputs. It works! Thank you.